# How to change value in variable type tensor in tensorflow kernel code?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I am trying to change output values in `ctx(OpKernelContext)` in Compute function. I could check the values by `tensor->flat<>()` when the operation is performed by constant.

However, I can't find them when the operation is performed by a variable. If I do `flat<>()`, it returns **segmentation error**. I want to access the values of outputs in some operation which have some variable inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible to reproduce with more detail about what you tried.

That said, directly accessing the content of variable tensors shouldn't lead to a segfault. What does is if you try to dereference a pointer to GPU memory in a CPU kernel, which might be what is happening here.

Comment: Thanks for reply. I got the seg error when I read the value of ref(variable) in cpu(Compute function before launch the gpu kernel). I just concluded that I read the value which is not in cpu(it would be in gpu). Is that right?